# Daily means with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I have a masked numpy array like this:

data =

```
[[0.0 8.51796269417e-06 0.271666675806]
 [1800.0 -2.32499992847e-06 -0.279374957085]
 [3600.0 5.99944460392e-06 -0.65399992466]
 ..., 
 [94602600.0 -- -1.56833326817]
 [94604400.0 -- 0.414166599512]
 [94606200.0 -- 1.50900006294]]
```

where in the first column is time (in seconds) and in other columns I have some data. I want to calculate daily mean values using the "numpy approach". I succeeded to do it like this:

```
days = np.unique(data[:,0]//86400)
daily = np.empty((len(days),3))
for idx,day in enumerate(days): daily[idx,:] = np.mean(data[np.where(data[:,0]//86400 == day)],axis=0)
```

However, I'm not satisfied with this, because (1) I lose the mask, (2) I would like to avoid loops and use only array operations.

Is there some effective numpy scripting to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your data by day and then perform means along only the desired axis. To do this it is easiest to either strip the array down to whole days (or you can pad it out to whole days).

```
# calculate number of complete days
nseconds = 94606200 - 94606200%86400
ndays = nseconds/86400

#calculate how many rows this corresponds to
nrows =  (nseconds)/1800 # =52512

nrows_per_day = 86400/1800

new_array = orig_array[:nrows].reshape(ndays,nrows_per_day,3)
```

Now to get the mean by day you can transpose the array and perform the mean only long the desired axis:

```
dailymean_1,dailymean_2 = new_array.transpose()[1:].mean(axis=1)
```

The above returns two arrays of length `ndays` which contain the daily means of columns 1 and 2 respectively from the original array.

Comment: Great. That's what I've asked.

However, what could be done if the data are not regular on the timescale (different number of points per day)?